# Represents empty type in C++ class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

consider the following example of a compile-time "vector".

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n, int...ns>
struct static_vector {
    static constexpr int value = n;
    static_vector<ns...> rest;
};

template <int n>
struct static_vector<n> {
    static constexpr int value = n;
    void* rest;
};

template <int n, class sv>
constexpr int access_nth() {
    static_assert(n >= 0, "vector size out of bound");
    if constexpr(n == 0) {
        return sv::value;
    } else {
        static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(sv::rest), void *>, "vector size out of bound");
        return access_nth<n-1, decltype(sv::rest)>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = static_vector<12, 23, 34, 45>();
    constexpr int nth = access_nth<5, decltype(a)>();
    std::cout << nth << std::endl;
}
```

I am mostly satisfied with what we can do now: define a vector and then get the nth element out of it. The one thing I found that not satisfying is this: I have to use `void *` as a dummy in the base case (where the vector only holds one element and no tail...)

I tried to have a specialisation like this:

```
template <>
struct static_vector<> {
}
```

to represent the empty vector. But it seems that the compiler always rejects this definition with the following error:

```
<source>:16:8: error: too few template arguments for class template 'static_vector'

struct static_vector<> {

       ^
```

What should I do here so I can have an empty vector?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess, having 2 structures with the same name is not a good idea. Its probably trying to instantiate the upper struct

Comment: Why do you need `void* rest` in the base class? If you remove it, your code still compiles. And why not to use `std::integer_sequence<int, ...>`? You can easily get n-th element from it by unpacking it into array and returning n-th element of that array.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EGGWGZ)

Comment: @Evg note how I would intend to use the access_nth function `constexpr int nth = access_nth<5, decltype(a)>();` I believe you implementation does not do the exact same thing.

Comment: @dorafmon, yes, sure. But you can easily modify it to meet your needs: [Demo 2](https://godbolt.org/z/gS9wk_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But why recursion ?

You tagged C++17 so you can use template folding, so... what about as follows ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int ... Is>
struct static_vector
 {
   template <std::size_t N>
   int get () const
    {
      static_assert( N < sizeof...(Is), "index out of bound" );

      std::size_t i{};
      int ret;

      ( ... , (N == i++ ? ret = Is : 0) );

      return ret;
    }
 };


int main()
 {
   constexpr auto a = static_vector<12, 23, 34, 45>();

   std::cout << a.get<3u>() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: One drawback of a member function template is that in generic code [we'll have to add](https://godbolt.org/z/YJghHm) ugly `template` disambiguator: `a.template get<3>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Specializations must conform to the base template declaration.  Since at least one `int` is required by the base template, this does not compile.

You can make this work by declaring the template to take any number of `int` arguments, then specializing every case that takes one or more arguments.  The base declaration is then the empty case:

```
template <int...>
struct static_vector {
    // Instantiated only for the no-argument case
};

template <int n>
struct static_vector<n> {
    // One-argument specialization
};

template <int n, int... ns>
struct static_vector<n, ns...> {
    // Two-or-more-argument specialization
};
```

Comment: You can also merge the declaration and the no-argument specialization: `template <int...> struct static_vector { };`. But, maybe, is less clear.

Comment: @max66 Yep, realized that probably at the same time you did (already edited that in).